# rename author base from author url in wordpress not working

Tags: url-rewriting, author

I am using the below code for rename author base, But its not working for me. I already save Settings>>permalinks from admin section.

Please let me know what error in below code.

```
add_action('init','change_author_base_permalinks');
function change_author_base_permalinks()
{
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->author_base = 'hire'; // Change 'member' to be the base URL you wish to use
    $wp_rewrite->author_structure = '/' . $wp_rewrite->author_base. '/%author%';
}
```

Comment: Your code looks fine as far as I can tell. Did you save the permalinks again after adding this action?

Comment: I just spun up a local test site, pasted your code in, resaved my permalinks under **Settings->Permalinks** and `local.dev/author/me` became `local.dev/hire/me`. Edited your function again to change `'hire'` to `'person'`, re-saved again and it changed again.

Comment: thanks for reply now its working fine.  Its was not working due to cache.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it was something simple. Is this rewrite part of a plugin? If so, you can write an action and add `flush_rewrite_rules();` to it and have it run both as an activation and deactivation hook.